# Can I substitute just yolks in a recipe that calls for a whole egg?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, yolk

I have a cookie recipe that only needs one whole egg. Since I have lots of yolks from other baking, can I use 1 yolk with something else (like a Tbsp. of water) or can I use 2 egg yolks?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/32511/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/24096/67

Comment: There are recipes which specifically call for egg yolks, in particular custards and certain cakes. Probably better to make one of those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use just egg yolks when recipe asks for eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/can-you-use-just-egg-yolks-when-recipe-asks-for-eggs)

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Please take a look at the questions that Joe links, above.  The answers there have a complete answer to your question (summary: it depends).

Answer (score 3):

From [Cook's Thesaurus Eggs](http://www.foodsubs.com/Eggs.html):

> Substitute 2 egg yolks for each whole egg. This is higher in fat, but works wonders in sauces, custards, and cream fillings.

I suggest you use two egg yolks, and perhaps *slightly*, almost unnoticeably, lower the amount of fat you put in the dough.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your goal is. It will work chemically, per [the other answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/113102/78544). But you will definitely get a much stronger egg flavor in the dish. In some dishes, this is acceptable or even desirable. In others, it could be distracting.

My preference is to use the yolks in recipes that actually call for extra yolks. For example, ice cream. :)